# Unix Script loop through individual variables in a list and execute code

Tags: string, bash, loops, variables, unix

I have been busting my head all day long without coming up with a sucessfull solution.

Setup:
We have Linux RHEL 8.3 and a file, script.sh

There is an enviroment variable set by an application with a ***dynamic*** string in it.

```
export PROGARM_VAR="abc10,def20,ghi30"
```

> > The delimiter is always "," and the values inside vary from 1 to 20.
>
> Inside the script I have defined 20 variables which take the values
>
> > using "**cut**" command I take each value and assign it to a variable

```
  var1=$(echo $PROGARM_VAR | cut -f1 -d,) 
  var2=$(echo $PROGARM_VAR | cut -f2 -d,)  
  var3=$(echo $PROGARM_VAR | cut -f3 -d,)  
  var4=$(echo $PROGARM_VAR | cut -f4 -d,)
  etc
```

In our case we will have:

```
var1="abc10" var2="def20" var3="ghi30" and var4="" which is empty
```

The loop must take each variable, test if its not empty and execute 10 pages of code using the tested variable. When it reaches an empty variable it should break.

Could you give me a hand please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split it with a comma. There are endless possibilities. You could:

```
10_pages_of_code() { echo "$1"; }
IFS=, read -a -r vars <<<"abc10,def20,ghi30"
for i in "${vars[@]}"; do 10_pages_of_code "$i"; done
```

or:

```
printf "%s" "abc10,def20,ghi30" | xargs -n1 -d, bash -c 'echo 10_pages_of_code "$1"' _
```

A safer code could use `readarray` instead of `read` to properly handle newlines in values, but I doubt that matters for you:

```
IFS= readarray -d , -t vars < <(printf "%s" "abc10,def20,ghi30")
```

You could also read in a stream up:

```
while IFS= read -r -d, var || [[ -n "$var" ]]; do
        10_pages_of_code "$var"
done < <(printf "%s" "abc10,def20,ghi30")
```

But still you could do it with cut... just actually write a loop and use an iterator.

```
i=0
while var=$(printf "%s\n" "$PROGARM_VAR" | cut -f"$i" -d,) && [[ -n "$var" ]]; do
      10_pages_of_code "$var"
      ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

or

```
echo "$PROGRAM_VAR" | tr , \\n | while read var; do
   : something with $var
done
```